# How to show dates on axis in Stacked Bar chart in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a stacked bar chart developed in Power BI which is bringing data for all the projects created in date and shows their actual as well planned budget. The chart also shows phases in which the project is currently now. Based on the data given, the graph is represetned like in the attached image shown.

[image]

As you can see the graph brings the project name (A & B) on Y-Axis and Duration In weeks on X-Axis. The duration in weeks is week difference between start date and end date. Instead, I now want 2 random dates to be displayed on the graph on X-Axis. The random dates could be anything like 01/01/2010 as start date and 01/01/2021 as end dates.

Alternatively, we can also take project start date and project end dates. Basically instead of duration in weeks on the X-Axis, I want dates (any kind)

Best regards

Comment: Are you looking for a kind of Gantt chart?
In that case, check out the custom visuals available

Comment: We did check Custom Visual for Gantt chart (the one by MAQ Software in Power BI visual Gallery) but that wasn't much helpful. We did require a legend to be displayed and currently the Gantt chart doesn't support the legends. Hence we switched to stacked chart but now that doesn't show dates on axis!!! Hence I'm stuck!